# My list activity wont open

Tags: android

Basically, my boidae list activity will not open from my serpente list activity. I am not sure why but i do have the log cat and code if you could possibly help me. Thankyou.

My log cat:

```
04-23 19:49:28.327: W/System.err(958): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xeecros.reptilekeeperBoidae
04-23 19:49:28.327: W/System.err(958):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-23 19:49:28.366: W/System.err(958):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
04-23 19:49:28.366: W/System.err(958):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
04-23 19:49:28.366: W/System.err(958):  at com.xeecros.reptilekeeper.Serpentes.onListItemClick(Serpentes.java:28)
04-23 19:49:28.366: W/System.err(958):  at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
04-23 19:49:28.366: W/System.err(958):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
04-23 19:49:28.366: W/System.err(958):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
04-23 19:49:28.366: W/System.err(958):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
04-23 19:49:28.376: W/System.err(958):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
04-23 19:49:28.376: W/System.err(958):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-23 19:49:28.376: W/System.err(958):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 19:49:28.376: W/System.err(958):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 19:49:28.376: W/System.err(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-23 19:49:28.387: W/System.err(958):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 19:49:28.387: W/System.err(958):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 19:49:28.387: W/System.err(958):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-23 19:49:28.387: W/System.err(958):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-23 19:49:28.396: W/System.err(958):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 19:49:28.396: W/System.err(958): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xeecros/reptilekeeperBoidae
04-23 19:49:28.396: W/System.err(958):  ... 18 more
04-23 19:49:28.406: W/System.err(958): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xeecros.reptilekeeperBoidae" on path: /data/app/com.xeecros.reptilekeeper-1.apk
04-23 19:49:28.406: W/System.err(958):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
04-23 19:49:28.406: W/System.err(958):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-23 19:49:28.406: W/System.err(958):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-23 19:49:28.416: W/System.err(958):  ... 18 more
```

my boidae class:

```
/*
 * This class is a list to contain
 * all of the classes for the individual species.
 */


package com.xeecros.reptilekeeper;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Boidae extends ListActivity {

    String boaspecies[] = {"Charina bottae"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Boidae.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, boaspecies));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String localposm = boaspecies[position];
        try{
            Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.xeecros.reptilekeeper" + localposm);
            Intent bintent = new Intent(Boidae.this, ourclass);
            startActivity(bintent);
            }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }





}
```

my serpente class:

```
package com.xeecros.reptilekeeper;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Serpentes extends ListActivity {

    String snakefam[] = {"Boidae", "Colubridae",
            "Elapidae", "Pythonidae", "Viperidae"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Serpentes.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, snakefam));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String localposm = snakefam[position];
        try{
        Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.xeecros.reptilekeeper" + localposm);
        Intent sintent = new Intent(Serpentes.this, ourclass);
        startActivity(sintent);
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Also, i have one other question: How do i change the appearance of the lists as i cant use xml because its an ArrayAdapter.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

change the following line

```
Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.xeecros.reptilekeeper" + localposm);
```

by putting this one instead

```
Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.xeecros.reptilekeeper." + localposm);
```

Note the . missing as the Error log suggest it :

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.xeecros.reptilekeeperBoidae
```

Comment: silly mistake there thank you, but also do you know how i would go about changing the appearance.

Comment: i did wonder about that but that didn't come in mind. Ill bear it in mind next time.

Comment: What do you mean ? You can always make a new question about appearances.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this (in class *Boidae*):

```
String boaspecies[] = {"Charina bottae"};
....
String localposm = boaspecies[position];
...
Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.xeecros.reptilekeeper" + localposm);
```

This can't work because *Charina bottae* can't be a class name.

Finally you missed the dots (in classes *Boidae* and *Serpentes*):

```
Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.xeecros.reptilekeeper." + localposm);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Nice spot there's also errors in the Boidae class but the question is about not being able to start the Boidae class. +1 anyway for more errors